# Combining 2 table to 1 Selectlist

Tags: asp.net-core

i want to ask?
i'm just make selectlist but i want my selectlist is provide 2 table.
in my Chartaccount Tabel

```
+---------+---------+
|Kodeakun |Namaakun |
--------------------|
|10000    |Asset    |
|20000    |Utang    |
|30000    |Modal    |
+-------------------+
```

in my controler

```
public IActionResult Create()`
{
List<ChartAccount> categorylist = new List<ChartAccount>();
categorylist = (from category in _context.ChartAccount select category).ToList();
categorylist.Insert(0, new ChartAccount { Id = 0, Kodeakun = 0, Namaakun = "Select", Saldo = 0 });
ViewBag.listofcategory = categorylist;
return View();
}
```

in my view

```
<select asp-for="Kodeakun" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.listofcategory,"Kodeakun","Namaakun"))"></select>
```

i try to but didnt work

```
<select asp-for="Kodeakun" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.listofcategory,"Kodeakun","Kodeakun"+"Namaakun"))"></select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 2 tables? I only see `ChartAccount`. Do you mean two columns? Do you want to show `10000 Asset` as text in SelectList?

Comment: Yup, im sorry. i want my view to `10000 Asset`

Comment: @TaoZhou and can you provide me a way how proper join on linq? after i join the ASP Action (EDIT, DETAILS, DELETE) not routing correctly. here my code in controller

    `var transaction1 = (from p in _context.Transaction join k in _context.ChartAccount on p.KodeakunK equals k.Kodeakun
                               select new Transaction {
                               KodeakunD = p.KodeakunD + k.Namaakun,
                               KodeakunK = p.KodeakunK + k.Namaakun}).ToList();
                
            return View(transaction1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to return `10000 Asset` in `ViewBag.listofcategory` like

```
List<ChartAccount> categorylist = new List<ChartAccount>() {
    new ChartAccount{ Id = 1, Kodeakun = 10000, Namaakun = "K1"},
    new ChartAccount{ Id = 2, Kodeakun = 20000, Namaakun = "K2"},
    new ChartAccount{ Id = 3, Kodeakun = 30000, Namaakun = "K3"}
};
var categorySelectList = categorylist.Select(c => {
    return new { Key = c.Id , Value = c.Kodeakun + " " + c.Namaakun  };
}).ToList();
categorySelectList.Insert(0, new { Key = 0, Value = "Select" });

ViewBag.listofcategory = categorySelectList;
```

And View like

```
<select class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.listofcategory,"Key","Value"))"></select>
```